# invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::basic_ostream<char>' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
int D(int raduis){
    return (raduis*2);
}
int main(){
   int num,raduis;
   std::cout<<"Enter your raduis : ";
   std::cin>>raduis;
   num = std::cout<<"Daimeter of given interger is :"<<D(raduis);
}
```

What have I done wrong in this program? Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: It looks like you wanted to write either `num = D(raduis); std::cout << "...text..." << num;` or `std::cout << "...text..." << D(raduis);` but ended up with a combination of them instead.

Answer (score 3):

In this line,

```
num = std::cout<<"Daimeter of given interger is :"<<D(raduis);
```

you are trying to assign the return value of `std::cout << ...` to an integer named `num`. This won't work, because the operator overload `<<` for streams return a reference to the streams themselves (for it to be chainable, i.e., multiple `<<` followed by each other), not something that you can assign to an `int`. You can instead remove the `num =` part and turn it into a pure output statement:

```
std::cout<<"Daimeter of given interger is :"<<D(raduis);
```

Comment: Can you explain in brief .so that I can understand?

Comment: Hm, I tried - can you point me to the part that you couldn't understand?

Comment: Staring form : "operator overload <<"  till : " can assign to an int "

Comment: `std::cout << "some string";` invokes an "operator overload". Operators are `+`, `-` and so on, but also `<<` or `>>`. C++ allowos them to be "overloaded", i.e. for other than builtin types you can define what these operators are supposed to do with them, `std::cout` is an object with an overloaded `<<` operator which is used for output streaming. Operator overloads are very similar to ordinary functions, and they also have a return type. This return type must be compatible with the type of the object which you are assigning the return value of an operator overload. This wasn't the case here.

Answer (score 2):

operator<< in basic_ostream returns another std::basic_ostream & so you can chain << operators.

You are assigning it to an int.

The <<operator is like a normal function in C++, it just has special syntax. If it was named write you would have had to write.

```
cout.write("diameter").write(D(radius));
```

write returns another basic_ostream so you can go on forever

```
cout.write().write().write()
```

So that's why it doesnt make sense to assign the return value of the last write to an int